# How to pass a bidimensional matrix by parameter to a function in C

Tags: c, dynamic, matrix, global

I have a question about matrices.
I have a program to calculate checkers moves; I solved it in Java, but it won't run fast enough and I decided to try it in C.

The problem is that in Java I can pass a bidimensional matrix as a parameter to a function, but I can't do it in C.  The compiler says that I can't. I dig here and on the web, and saw something of dynamic allocation and things like this, but I don't really understand.

My problem is:

- How can I pass a bidimensional matrix to my function, `checagem` (it's a recursive function) to make this work?
- And is this working (the `main()` code), because here it show a 0 loop? I don't know if it is because of the matrix or what.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int checagem(int m[][100], int xo, int xd, int yd, int n) {
    int r = 0;
    if (0 <= xd && xd < n && 0 <= yd && yd < n) {
        if (yd == 0) {
            if (m[yd][xd] != 1) {
                r += 1;
            }
        } else if (m[yd][xd] == 0 || m[yd][xd] == 2) {
            r += checagem(m, xd, xd - 1, yd - 1, n);
            r += checagem(m, xd, xd + 1, yd - 1, n);
        } else if (m[yd][xd] == 1) {
            if (xo - xd > 0) {
                if (pulavel(xd - 1, yd - 1, m, n)==1) {
                    r += checagem(m, xd, xd - 1, yd - 1, n);
                }
            } else if (xo - xd < 0) {
                if (pulavel(xd + 1, yd - 1, m, n)==1) {
                    r += checagem(m, xd, xd + 1, yd - 1, n);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        r += 0;
    }
    return r;
}

int pulavel(int x, int y, int m[][100], int n) {
    int r = 1;
    if (x < 0 || x > n - 1 || m[y][x] == 1) {
       r=0 ;
    }
    return r;
}

int main(){
    //variaveis
    int n = 0, t = 1, x = -1, y = -1, teste = 1;
    int i,j;
    //logica
    scanf("%d %*c",&t);

    while (teste > 0) {
        scanf("%d %*c",&n);
        if (n > 1 || n <= 100) {
            int tabuleiro[n][n];
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                char l[n];
                scanf("%s %*c", &l);
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
                    switch(l[j]){
                    case ('.'): tabuleiro[i][j] = 0;break;
                    case ('b'): tabuleiro[i][j] = 1;break;
                    case ('w'): tabuleiro[i][j] = 2;
                                x = j;
                                y = i;break;
                    }
                }
            }
            int r = checagem(tabuleiro, x, x, y, n);
            printf("%d", r); 
        }
    }
}
```

The input is like the contest from: http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=3108

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you declare `int tabuleiro[n][n];` in your `main()` function, but your `checagem()` function does not expect to be passed a VLA.  You need to pass the dimension before the array, so revise it to be:

```
int checagem(int n, int m[n][n], int xo, int xd, int yd)
{
    ...
}
```

Then make sure you don't overflow the bounds of the array (because C won't stop you, of course).

You will need to make a parallel change to `pulavel()`, and change the calls to both functions, of course.

This compiles OK; I've not tried running it.  Don't take addresses of arrays; it will confuse you, even if it doesn't confuse the compiler (it just whinged about the type mismatch in `scanf("%s %*c", &l);`).  Do upgrade your code to check that the `scanf()` calls succeed.  I'm not sure what format you're reading with `scanf("%s %*c", l)`, but I suspect it is doing damage to the data that you don't expect.  I reordered the functions and made them `static` (and added `void` to `int main(void)`) to avoid compilation warnings from my standard GCC compilation options:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -c ck.c
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static
int pulavel(int n, int x, int y, int m[n][n])
{
    int r = 1;
    if (x < 0 || x > n - 1 || m[y][x] == 1)
       r=0;
    return r;
}

static
int checagem(int n, int m[n][n], int xo, int xd, int yd)
{
    int r = 0;
    if (0 <= xd && xd < n && 0 <= yd && yd < n) {
        if (yd == 0) {
            if (m[yd][xd] != 1) {
                r += 1;
            }
        } else if (m[yd][xd] == 0 || m[yd][xd] == 2) {
            r += checagem(n, m, xd, xd - 1, yd - 1);
            r += checagem(n, m, xd, xd + 1, yd - 1);
        } else if (m[yd][xd] == 1) {
            if (xo - xd > 0) {
                if (pulavel(n, xd - 1, yd - 1, m)==1) {
                    r += checagem(n, m, xd, xd - 1, yd - 1);
                }
            } else if (xo - xd < 0) {
                if (pulavel(n, xd + 1, yd - 1, m)==1) {
                    r += checagem(n, m, xd, xd + 1, yd - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        r += 0;
    }
    return r;
}

int main(void)
{
    //variaveis
    int n = 0, t = 1, x = -1, y = -1, teste = 1;
    int i,j;
    //logica
    scanf("%d %*c",&t);

    while (teste > 0) {
        scanf("%d %*c",&n);
        if (n > 1 || n <= 100) {
            int tabuleiro[n][n];
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                char l[n];
                scanf("%s %*c", l);
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
                    switch(l[j]){
                    case ('.'): tabuleiro[i][j] = 0;break;
                    case ('b'): tabuleiro[i][j] = 1;break;
                    case ('w'): tabuleiro[i][j] = 2;
                                x = j;
                                y = i;break;
                    }
                }
            }
            int r = checagem(n, tabuleiro, x, x, y);
            printf("%d", r); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tanks Jonathan Leffler, i consider you so much. You're right, i misscoded the main() (the other functions too, but their logic is correct) i have now the 'read a string, separete the chars and compare it' problem.. i'll try search in StackOverflow (i saw somethings of this) and try your solution (i can't test already) but my sincere tanks to you.^^